# combining observations based on a criteria in R

Tags: r, aggregate

I have a data set that looks like this:

```
    geoid   zip dealers Year    County
    1001    36703   1   2001    Autauga County, AL
    1001    36704   3   2001    Autauga County, AL
    1003    36535   7   2000    Baldwin County, AL
    1003    36536   3   2000    Baldwin County, AL
```

And I want to take all the rows that are the same except for 'dealers' and 'zip' and combine them into one row with the dealer variable summed from all the similar rows. (I'm not sure what the easiest thing is to do with zip, either list them all or leave it out? Doesn't really matter.) So this would become:

```
    geoid   dealers Year    County  
    1001    4   2001    Autauga County, AL
    1003    10  2000    Baldwin County, AL
```

Is there any way to create a new dataset like this? (Incidentally, I got here by merging three datasets, so if there's a better way to merge without creating these duplicates, that would be helpful as well.)

Comment: Your question is more about `aggregate` than `merge`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This gives you the desired result:

```
df <- read.table(header=TRUE, text=
'geoid   zip dealers Year    County
1001    36703   1   2001    "Autauga County, AL"
1001    36704   3   2001    "Autauga County, AL"
1003    36535   7   2000    "Baldwin County, AL"
1003    36536   3   2000    "Baldwin County, AL"')

aggregate(dealers ~ geoid+Year+County, data=df[-2], FUN=sum) # or
aggregate(dealers ~ geoid+Year+County, data=df, FUN=sum)
```